# I am unable to install web3 on my mac

Tags: web3js

I tried to install web3 in my mac by using `sudo npm install web3` but failed many a times . Please help me to sort this matter out . i am attaching you the exact error that I am facing while running above command.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a Node question more so.

But most likely your issues lies here:

> `no such file or directory, open '/Users/saitejakuruva/package.json'`

You're not in a proper project directly when calling `npm install`.
NPM was trying to write to, or update, the `package.json` file.

Try `npm install -g web3` which will install web3 at a global level available to all projects.

This may go against best practices elsewhere per project, so be aware.

Update:

Link to fixing permission issues with Mac and NPM:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252451/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-modules-in-osx/47252840

Comment: So sorry. I tried using the command suggested by you but I facing the same issue. Please find the details of the issue here https://i.imgur.com/PZgZkDH.png

Comment: Well, it's a small step in the right direction. No longer is the `package.json` error showing. But it's still an access permissions error when creating new directories. 

Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252451/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-modules-in-osx/47252840

Does that help?

Comment: It doesn't work for me again getting the same error. :(

Comment: how about `yarn global add web3` ?

Comment: What is this? I'm unable to understand this can you please explain me in detail please

Comment: Yarn is another package manager. Read more here: https://code.fb.com/web/yarn-a-new-package-manager-for-javascript/. 

Overall - from the details I know about. it sounds like you have a permissions configuration gone bad. At this point, if you still count get npm to work. I'd uninstall completely and reinstall.